# Symfony custom log handler service call

Tags: symfony, logging, containers, handler, monolog

I have created custom log handler in symfony. Creating it was not a problem, config: config/packages/dev/monolog.yaml

```
monolog:
    handlers:
     ....
        alerts:
            type: service
            id: App\Logger\AlertLogger
            channels: [app]
            level:  warning
```

And my service:

```
<?php

namespace App\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler;
class AlertLogger extends AbstractProcessingHandler
{
    protected function write(array $record)
    {
        // handle log
    }
}
```

But the problem is that I want to send this logs to RabbitMQ and do something in Consumer, but there is no way to call any other Service. I tried to pass it to construct, but I am getting errors like:

> Argument 3 passed to App\Logger\AlertLogger::__construct() must implement interface OldSound\RabbitMqBundle\RabbitMq\ProducerInterface, string given, called in .....

Thats because there is a construct definition in AbstractProcessingHandler.

=============== EDIT: My tests:

Parents class constructor:

```
public function __construct($level = Logger::DEBUG, $bubble = true)
{
    $this->setLevel($level);
    $this->bubble = $bubble;
}
```

I tried to add log handler as a service to services.yaml:

```
services:
    .....
    App\Logger\AlertLogger:
        arguments:
            $producer: OldSound\RabbitMqBundle\RabbitMq\Producer
```

And my log handler:

```
...
class AlertLogger extends AbstractProcessingHandler
{
    /**
     * @var ProducerInterface
     */
    private $producer;
    public function __construct(ProducerInterface $producer)
    {
        $this->producer = $producer;
    }
  ......
```

But Im getting this error:

> Argument 1 passed to App\Logger\AlertLogger::__construct() must implement interface OldSound\RabbitMqBundle\RabbitMq\ProducerInterface, string given, called in

When I try to set construct arguments:

```
....
class AlertLogger extends AbstractProcessingHandler
{
    /**
     * @var ProducerInterface
     */
    private $producer;
    public function __construct($level, $bubble, ProducerInterface $producer)
    {
        parent::__construct($level, $bubble);
        $this->producer = $producer;
    }
.....
```

I got error:

> Cannot autowire service "App\Logger\AlertLogger": argument "$level" of method "__construct()" has no type-hint, you should configure its value explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucas, in order to override your constructor arguments you should define custom constructor for it and configure service definition for (if not autowired). Unfortunately this leads to loss of predefined functionality (i.e `level` setting is useless here), so you have to re-define it by yourself.

If handler defined as a service it's really not processed in any way

https://github.com/symfony/monolog-bundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/MonologExtension.php#L131-L135

You can try post you constructor and service definition to get more specific answers on their state. On first look I can suggest that you've created the service definition by hand and forgot the `@` sign. Just a guess.

Edit:

should be

```
services:
    .....
    App\Logger\AlertLogger:
        arguments:
            $level: 'warning'
            $bubble: true
            $producer: "@OldSound\RabbitMqBundle\RabbitMq\Producer"
```

With constructor

```
/**
 * @var ProducerInterface
 */
private $producer;
public function __construct($level, $bubble, ProducerInterface $producer)
{
    parent::__construct($level, $bubble);
    $this->producer = $producer;
}
```

Comment: So yes, you are putting string to a constructor. prepens it with @ and wrap with quotes

Comment: @Lucas I've updated my answer, check it for possible solutoin

Comment: I think that this is good direction, because Im getting a error that OldSound\RabbitMqBundle\RabbitMq\Producer is unknown service. There is a problem with service definition order or something like that. Do you have any idea how to force that?

Comment: Are you sure, that `@OldSound\RabbitMqBundle\RabbitMq\Producer` really exists? I hope producers are registered dynamically and there can be multiple of them, so you can get the bundle documentation to find out how is your producer service is named

Comment: Great, It works, the problem was that i passed '@OldSound\RabbitMqBundle\RabbitMq\Producer' as a $producer, but It had to be '@old_sound_rabbit_mq.alerts_producer' Thanks !